# ActionName при подключении в Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

Нашёл параметр, который не могу понять. 
На сайте оракла описан как:

> Using the ActionName property allows the application to set the action
>   name in the application context for a given OracleConnection object.

используется при создании подключения примерно так:

```
private void InitConnection() {
    if (null == connection_) {
        connection_ = new OracleConnection(connection_string_);
        connection_.Open();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(action_name_)) {
            // ActionName появился только в 11.1.0.7.0 - поэтому динамически устанавливаем
            var action_name_prop = connection_.GetType().GetProperty("ActionName");
            if (null != action_name_prop) {
                action_name_prop.SetValue(connection_, action_name_, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код писался давно и не мной, пытаюсь разобрать некоторые нюансы, но описание

> ActionName property to set the action name

Мне кажется крайне туманным. Кто-нить сталкивался? Зачем оно вообще нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, этой строкой вы установите наименование подключения для представления v$session
т.е. в

```
select module, action from v$session
```

вы увидите в поле module наименование вашего приложения, например PL/SQL Developer, в action текущую активность, например SQL Window - New